# CSS nth child - selecting wrong span element inside href

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to use the CSS `nth-child` selector to style the third span tag inside a `href`, so the `href` is the parent effectively. It doesn't seem to work, it either style all of them or none at all.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="h3">
<span class="arr-bottom arrow-down chev-align">&nbsp;</span>
    <a href="#" class="">
        <span class="qFaq">First span</span>
        <span class="">Second span</span>
        <span class="faqChevron fa fa-chevron-down fl-right f">Third Span</span>
    </a>
```

The CSS looks like this:

```
 div.h3 > a:nth-of-type(3) > span {
    color:#999;
  }
```

I've set up a JS Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/db1wsbbo/1/.

Comment: Sorry, the right JS Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/db1wsbbo/1/

Comment: You can edit your question to replace the link, I've done it for you. Please include all code in the question, we shouldn't have to go to an external site to see your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're selecting the 3rd anchor not the 3rd span.
http://jsfiddle.net/db1wsbbo/2/

```css
.nth span:nth-child(3) {
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="h3">
  <span class="arr-bottom arrow-down chev-align">&nbsp;</span>
  <a href="#" class="nth">
    <span class="qFaq">Q</span>
    <span class="">This is a span</span>
    <span class="faqChevron fa fa-chevron-down fl-right f">grey color</span>
  </a>
</div>
```